# Implementing signin and signup routes with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement sign-in and sign-up routs using react-router-dom, and I'm not sure if what I came up with is the best way to achieve this goal, especially if I would like to implement redirect in the future.

```
//App.js

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={SignInSignUpPage}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// SignInSignUpPage
const SignInSignUpPage = () => {
  return (
    <SignInSignUpContainer />
  );
};
```

```
//SignInSignUpContainer
const SignInSignUpContainer = () => {
  return (
    <SignInSignUpContainerStyles>

      <SignInSignUpContaineHeader>
        <SignInSignUpContaineHeaderElement to="/">
          Sign in
        </SignInSignUpContaineHeaderElement>
        <SignInSignUpContaineHeaderElement to="/signup">
          Sign Up
        </SignInSignUpContaineHeaderElement>
      </SignInSignUpContaineHeader>

      <SignInSignUpContainerContent>
        <SignInSignUpContainerContentForm>
          <LockIconContainer iconName="icon-lock-closed" />

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />

            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          </Switch>

        </SignInSignUpContainerContentForm>
      </SignInSignUpContainerContent>
    </SignInSignUpContainerStyles>
```

As you can see, I have Links inside the SignInSignUpContainer component that will route to different component's, but they are actually routing to the exact same component and render base on conditional route's.

That feels hacky, how can I implement those routes better, so it will be easier to implement redirect base on sessions/user credentials in the future?

Comment: You might want to take a look at React Router's docs. They have a pretty good example of how to implement authorization routing with redirects: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Basically, you're going to have to probably implement some sort of state, as from the code you provided everything is stateless. That way you can track if the user is signed in and determine if they can access the PrivateRoute component.